# Microsft Azure: user id does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I received an invitation link to join the Azure Default Directory organization.
I accepted the invitation and sign in/sign up(don't remember) with my organization domain mail id.
Now when I am trying to login it is giving error as userid/password is incorrect. When I am trying to reset it, it is saying

> The user ID you entered does not exist. Please check that you have
>   typed your user ID correctly

When I checked with my admin, my user id is there with user type: Guest and Source: External AAD.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the response I received from Microsoft support and it resolved my issue.

If a user has been added successfully and you are unable to access, I suggest to reset your password by the Admin, as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-reset-password-azure-portal
If the Admin has not yet assigned a role to you, then please ask him to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It happens intermittently. You can follow these two steps.

1. Open your browser which is giving you an error.
2. Clear all history of Azure usages
3. Close Browser & Re-login

If you don''t want to clear browser.

1. Open browser in private\incognito mode
2. Open login URL
3. Login or reset your password.

PS: Azure has two login types one Work and Personal. If your account is create by your organization you can not reset the password. You need to contact you Azure administrator for changing the password.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I contacted my admin it is now resolved.